# How to express formally all possible 2-tuples of a set into one set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let be a triplet of sets $(A, B, R)$, where:

- $A = \{a, b, c, ...\}$
- $B = \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$
- $R$ denoted the set for relations for the elements of the sets $A$ and $B$, $R = \{(a, 1), (b, 2), (c, 3), ...\}$

I want to defined a new set that contains all elements from the set R, but without consider the relations, in a formal way. For example, $F = \{a, 1, b, 2, c, 3, ...\}$. I was thinking something like this:

$$F = \{(w_1, w_2) \in R | w_1 \in A \vee w_2 \in B \}$$

But I think it's not okay

Comment: Details depend on how you define tuple, but general idea is to transform each tuple into set of it's elements using axiom of replacement, and then take union of them using axiom of union.

Comment: Maybe
$$G = \{t: \exists s, \text{ so that } \{(t,s),(s,t)\}\cap GR \not= \emptyset  \},$$ but I am being informal about where $t,s$ live; you don't have a name for that set.

Comment: I updated the quetions

Comment: What is a "four set"?

Comment: sorry, I mean "a new set"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you accept the standard definition of $(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, then observe that $\bigcup (a,b) = \{a,b\}$, so your desired set is:
$$
\{a,1,b,2,c,3,\dots\} = \bigcup \{\{a,1\},\{b,2\},\{c,3\},\dots\} = \bigcup\bigcup \{(a,1),(b,2),(c,3),\dots\} = \bigcup \bigcup R
$$